# Using Nonce-field in Custom Meta Box plugin, unable to save data

Tags: wordpress, nonce

I have been struggling to create a plugin that would allow my customer to update their contact info. I've managed have the plugin show the fields in the admin-area of the frontpage (only want to show the info there). As I fill in the information & press update post, fields go blank and nothing gets saved.

I believe I've isolated the cause to the nonce-field, tested by having some of the fields in an `if-statement` where I tested for `isset & wp_verify_nonce`. The fields disappeared, thus the nonce isn't working correctly. What am I doing wrong?

This is my first Wordpress-site that I'm working on so the solution of using multiple fields might not be the most clever but seemed the most simple to wrap my head around.

As a side question, am I right in assuming that I can echo the contents of a field (for example the 'h3_nimi' by using `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'h3_nimi', true );`?

Hopefully it's ok to use pastebin to avoid cluttering the post as the code is rather long due to multiple fields? Thank you in advance.

http://pastebin.com/fqRW2Yyx

Answer (score 0):

Your nonce is created as `tt-tallennus` but you are checking against `tt_henkilosto` so the check will always fail.

Comment: Thank you for spotting it, I changed it to ´if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['tt_nonce_kentta'], 'tt-tallennus' ) ) {
  return;
 }´ but it still it does not work.

Comment: I've been testing it with `if (  isset( $_POST['tt_nonce_kentta'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['tt_nonce_kentta'], 'tt-tallennus' ) )` and both parts of it and it fails even on the `isset`. Do I have another naming mistake or is it not simply saving the nonce for some reason I can't understand?

Comment: Do you have a debugger setup or another way of looking at what is in $_POST?

Comment: After Googling a bit, I enabled debugging in wordpress config, this `Undefined variable: post in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\plugins\tt-metabox-text-employees\tt-meta-employees.php on line xx` and `Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\plugins\tt-metabox-text-employees\tt-meta-employees.php on line xx` repeat multiple times in debug.log. I tried `echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';` and got `array (size=0)
  empty`

Comment: The errors are because you are trying to use $post (first error) or $post->id in your metabox callbacks, but $post is not defined.

Try `global $post` before making this call, worth checking this gives what you want, not sure what the global $post object will be in this context.

Not sure why you're not getting anything in $_POST, how are you saving the post?

Comment: Thank you Max, I managed to bypass the problem by setting up a settings page. Turned out to be a lot easier than it seemed at first & easier than getting this to work. Perhaps I'll take another crack at it later.